# What terminal command would give me root's first (oldest) process?

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm looking for a command that would return root's oldest active process and what time the process what started.

Comment: `echo "init"`? :p

Comment: @Snubber please don't forget to accept the answer which you found most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
ps -ef pid,user,stime,cmd,etime --sort=-etime | grep root
```

But if you want the elapsed time in seconds then use `etimes` so you have:

```
ps -ef pid,user,stime,cmd,etimes --sort=-etimes | grep root
```

You can also use `-o` option in `ps` to be able to sort without having to list the column you are sorting on (see @choroba's comment below) like this:

```
ps -e -o pid,user,cmd --sort=-etime | grep root
```

Of course in your case you do need to see the time, but it is an extra option just in case as noted below by @choroba.

Comment: Sorting by pid tells you nothing about the age of the process.

Comment: @choroba Thanks for pointing it out for me. I now sorted on `etime`, what do you think?

Comment: I'd say `etimes` is even better.

Comment: @choroba Thanks guru, but for readability wouldn't `etime` be better, I guess I'm just wondering you think listing seconds is better.

Comment: Compare the outputs on a sufficiently long running machine.

Comment: @choroba ah ok. Thank you for responding. I added the option `etimes` for the user as you suggested. Is this okay or does it still need improvement?

Comment: You don't need to output the field you're sorting on. `diff -y <(ps -e -opid,etime,etimes --sort=etime) <(ps -e -opid,etime,etimes --sort=etimes)` should show you what I mean.

Comment: @choroba very neat thanks for noting. I added the extra option to my answer just in case the user finds it convenient, and I referred him to your comment for the source of the extra comment.